# Apache mod_rewrite in IIS

Tags: laravel, apache, iis, mod-rewrite

Installing Laravel 5.7 in a IIS server, what are the equivalent of Apache's mod-rewrite rules to IIS?

The IIS built in auto converter throws an error on it's conversion tool.

**APACHE RULES**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**IIS ERRORS**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--The rule cannot be converted into an equivalent IIS format because of unsupported flags: E-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,

VictorBarna

Comment: I suggest you could refer to below web.config to know how to run the Laravel in IIS. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/web.config

Comment: I guess in the end this is a configuration issue. If you're not familiar with IIS (which I assume based on the way this was asked), the best suggestion I can give is that you contact the system administrator that is taking care of IIS. If you're also not familiar with Apache and your new system administrator is not as well, you need to bring together your old and new system administrators so they can translate the configuration between the two webservers. [This is documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules#disclaimer)

Comment: The final solution was with editing the web.config file.

Thank you so much for your help! If i had permissions I would mark your answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was editing the web.config file.

In this case, for Laravel 5.7 and IIS, with the value:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```